# .Net Code formatting, 'in lining'

Tags: c#

Consider this contrived example :

```
public static string ContrivedOne(Guid id, string host)
{
    Contact person = new Contact(host, id);
    DbRow record = new DbRow(host);
    string msg = string.Format("Hi, {0}", host);
    StuffItems stuff = GetStuff(id);
    string result = record.Save(person, stuff, msg);
    return result;
}


public static string ContrivedOner(Guid id, string host)
{
    return new DbRow(host).Save(new Contact(host, id), GetStuff(id), string.Format("Hi, {0}", host));
}
```

All things being equal, not considering legibility etc, would there typically be a difference in performance between them ?

Comment: Most likely, it wouldn't.

Comment: Afact neither can be said to be consistently faster without actually testing in practice, although technically there may be minuscule differences due to caching and that the methods are called in different order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference in performance that I can see is what is being put on the stack when.

In the first example, each function is called, and its return value is put on the stack into a local variable. In the second, its possible that the "Save" function call will get pushed, then each of the ones in the arguments (still storing to a hidden local variable).

All those details are determined by the compiler of course. As far as an actual (read, noticeable) performance difference, you aren't going to see anything.

Comment: Confirms my suspicion : sometimes the compiler will come up with  something 'clever'/faster, sometimes not. So, like Joachim suggested, you'd have to test each case.  But in general the potential gain doesn't way up against the pain. Thanks.